# Pandas df: exponentiate whole row when a condition is true

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in Python (I am using Python 3.6).

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like following:

```
import pandas as pd
data_exp = [['no', 2,1.5,3], ['exp', 2,1.5,3], ['no', 2,1.5,5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Type', 'V1','V2','V3'])
df
```

What I want to do is the following:

if `type` in the first column of the database is equal to `exp`, then I want to `exp()` all the values on the same row from column 2 to the last one. If else, simply do not change the values in the other columns.

So the output would be:

```
data = [[2,1.5,3], [7.39,4.48,20.09], [2,1.5,5]]
```

Any idea how to do it? The function `np.exp(df.iloc[i,1:])` for each value of i in the row numbering does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for both sides with boolean mask - compare values by `exp` in `Type` column, converting mask to numpy array is for prevent `NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available`:

```
m = df['Type'].eq('exp').to_numpy()
#for oldier pandas version
m = df['Type'].eq('exp').values
df.iloc[m,1:] = np.exp(df.iloc[m,1:])
print(df)
  Type        V1        V2         V3
0   no  2.000000  1.500000   3.000000
1  exp  7.389056  4.481689  20.085537
2   no  2.000000  1.500000   5.000000
```

Comment: In defining m, I get the following error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: @Vitomir - then use `m = df['Type'].eq('exp').values` or upgrade pandas